# H1 extra whitespace

Tags: css, whitespace

I have a php file on my test server, and it outputs the following:
[image]

There is some extra white space on the page, highlighted by the red box.
Dev tools view:
[image]
The extra whitespace is highlighted in the dev tools.
File that is outputted:
[image]
As you can see, all of the file is on one line.

Code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    if(!isset($_GET['action']))
    {
        $_GET['action'] = "home";
    }

echo("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
    echo("<html>");
        echo("<head>");
            echo("<title>Bug Tracker -  ");
            echo($_GET['action']);
            echo("</title>");
            echo('<link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" />');
        echo("</head>");
        echo('<body>');
            require("action.php"); 
        echo("</body>");
    echo("</html>")
?>
```

This happens in firefox as well.

Comment: Can we see your `common.css` ?

Comment: I believe your problem is in `CSS`, as `H1` has some huge margins defined, check bottom margin also.

Comment: here is common.css: http://pastebin.com/U03BDBy6

Comment: you only have that CSS ?

Comment: If action.php has whitespace before or after the <?php ?> tags it will be output too but wouldn't show as a break, it's the h1 and body tags having padding/margin by default.

Comment: If you want to see action.php, it is here: http://pastebin.com/jPp2PaWV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<h1>` tag usually has a default margin. Try to set `h1 { margin:0 }` in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. The whitespace is still there in the dev tools. This whitespace replaces the margin and so it looks as it should do. I will accept as the answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs you might consider learn about reset.css files

Answer (score 3):

I believe a h1 tag always has margin top and bottom that is why you are seeing the white space. If you add a margin-top: 0 to the h1 then it will remove the space above.

Comment: Don't forget that they body usually has a padding to it too

Answer (score 1):

In my CSS, setting the h1 margin to 0 fixed it for me.

CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more clear in what you want.

The white space in your browser is most likely due to action.php having white space in it. White space is only created because php prints HTML (or similar) to the browser. Remember that PHP runs server-side, so the browser doesn't actually download the php file, it only reads the HTML.

Check (or show us) your action.php file

Also try

```
echo "<h1 style='vertical-align:text-top;'>Bug tracker home page</h1>";
```

~ Dan

Comment: I check action.php, and it does not have any extra whitespace in. Solved it anyway(see below)!

Comment: depends on the browser. I think margin:0 is the best solution.

Comment: I agree for the moment. The extra whitespace does the jobb of the margin when you remove the margin.